# MVC 3 Forms Authentication not working in Internet Explorer keeps redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, forms-authentication

I have implented some lovely forms authentication in ASP.NET MVC 3, this has been working fantastic in Chrome. Now is the time test on the worlds worst browser, Internet Explorer. I just simply went to Log in, and the page just goes back to the login in page every time I click the submit button. The credentials are correct. I have stepped through the code, I am using a RedirectToAction to a page and no errors are being flagged it just goes straight back to the login page.

I should point out I have tried the following:

- Removed webmatrix dlls and dependancies
- Removed System.Web.Helpersn
- These have both been removed from the bin, the references and the
  bin_deploayableAssemblies folder in VS2010

I have also dded the following to the web.config appsettings:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/LoginReg/LogOn"/>
```

Here is my full web.config:

http://pastebin.com/t6cj6cSb

I should point out my login page is in a folder called: Login Reg, so the url would be /LoginReg/LogOn.

This works perfectly in chrome but for some reason doe not work in Internet Explorer.

Does anyone have any ideas hwo to fix this really annoying problem or have any useful articles

Thanks

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in IE?

Comment: I just looked in my settings and guess what...."Block all cookies"!!!!!!!!! It's friday and developers should not work past 4!! Thank you! The best answer is always the simplest, please put your comment as an answer so it can receive a tick! :)

Comment: I know there is a tendency to want to blame IE for every problem you discover with it, but in reality, 95% of the time it's not IE's fault, as you found out in this case.  IE has its issues for sure, but that's largely in the past, so long as you don't need to support IE6 (and with less than 2% of the population, mostly in China, still using it, there is very little reason to support IE6 anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms authentication creates a http cookie to maintain authentication state between requests. Make sure you have cookies enabled in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I found a weird solution to this problem, In my case, I have an MVC3 Solution, and of course my problem was the same as the original post, 
What I did is very weird:

1. I renamed the LogOn get/post method(s) to `LoginPageView`
2. Of course I created the corresponding VIEW to the `LoginPageView` Controller action

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult LoginPageView()
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```
3. I ran and I could redirect to any other controller action on the solution, of course taking care of the `[Authorize]` or not authorize attribute on my methods I need.
4. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that resolved my issue by adding a global filter to FilterConfig.cs file.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
       filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Now login works perfectly with Internet explorer and Microsoft Edge browser.